# how do you specify the x axis in ggplot2 histogram?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code to plot a histogram using ggplot2.

```
ggplot(data = plot, aes(x = total_Amg))+
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, colour = "black", fill = "white") +
  facet_wrap(~ gentamicin)
```

How can I specify what numbers are shown on the x axis of the resulting graph, i.e. show 0 to 8, rather than showing those that was automatically generated (see below)?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change x-axis breaks ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33191998/change-x-axis-breaks-ggplot2)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/22818899/5325862

Answer (score 1):

`+scale_x_continuous(breaks=0:8)` should do the trick

Comment: thank-you. I've tried this, and for one data set this works but for another it only shows 0 to 5? I want to show 0 to 8 for both graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
+ scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:8, labels = 0:8)
```